# Replace all values in a row with 0 if one of the variables has missing data

Tags: r, write.table

As the title states I'm attempting to replace all values in a given row with 0 if any variable has NA and output this using write.table. For example:

```
x  y  z
2  3  5
4  NA 1
3  2  1
```

to

```
x  y  z
2  3  5
0  0  0
3  2  1
```

At the moment my code looks like the following

```
myvars <- c("x", "y", "z")
newdata <- mydata[myvars]
write.table(newdata, "data.txt", col.names=FALSE, row.names=FALSE)
```

Comment: any reason for keeping those rows around as `0`s? I have a feeling you'll be better off just removing them entirely, unless you've got something particular in mind.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`complete.cases` seems appropriate here:

```
dat[!complete.cases(dat),] <- 0
dat
#  x y z
#1 2 3 5
#2 0 0 0
#3 3 2 1
```

Answer (score 5):

While the answer by @thelatemail is really cool,

It won't hurt to learn one more trick.

Here is my solution:

```
dat[rowSums(is.na(dat))>0,]<- 0
dat
#  v1 v2 v3
#1 2  3  5
#2 0  0  0
#3 3  2  1
```